# Simultaneous diagonalisation of all $2\times 2$ diagonalisable complex matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

I want to show that we can simultaneously diagonalise all $2\times 2$ diagonalisable complex matrices. I am attempting to do this by using the fact that if $A_1, ..., A_n$ are commuting matrices, then they can be simultaneously diagonalised.

However,

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 \end{pmatrix}$$

are both diagonalisable, but do not commute.

How should this be done?

Comment: Why are you trying to show this, and what makes you think you might be able to?

Comment: What do you mean by simultaneous diagonalisation? and more importantly, what does one achieve by diagonalising diagonalisable matrices simultaneously?

Comment: Suggestion. Do you understand that if $A$ is diagonalisable then there is a basis of eigenvectors? And that if the eigenvalues are distinct then the eigenvectors are unique up to scalar multiples? And that given any two linearly independent vectors then there is a linear transformation having these as eigenvectors with eigenvalues $1,-1$? Now what does that say about your conjecture?

Comment: @Nik: In quantum physics one often wants to simultaneously diagonalize as many operators (often represented by matrices) as possible.

Comment: Your plan works perfectly with $1\times1$ matrices.

Answer (score -1):

Since diagonal matrices commute, if two matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable then they have to commute. In particular, your example pair of matrices cannot be simultaneously diagonalized.